# .Net Rally.RestApi error "Not authorized to perform action: Invalid key" when creating Rally test folder

Tags: c#, rally

I have a C# application using version 2.0.1.0 of the Rally Rest API for .NET.  The application will successfully query Rally for data, but when I try to create an object, an error is returned indicating invalid key.  This issue started today and is occurring for multiple users of the application.
I use the following line of code to authenticate.

myRestApi = new RallyRestApi(Rally_username, Rally_password, Rally_URL, "v2.0", myProxy);

I have read some help online indicating the need for a security token, however this note makes me feel like that is not needed: "Note: When using any of the Rally REST Toolkits or the App SDK this will be automatically handled. "

I have tried updating to version 3.0 (Beta), but this does not resolve the problem.

Comment: Contact the owners of the Rally Rest API. Perhaps your account has been disabled.

Comment: My application also started getting the same error from today. I am using java api, I tried using the "apiKey" for a single user it works, but using username/password it keeps failing.

Comment: I have the same issue in that the "apiKey" works, but when using the username/password, it fails.

Comment: I am too getting the same problem since yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

There are reports that using ApiKey instead of basic authentication with username/password resolves the invalid key error.

Rally .NET toolkit supports [ApiKey](https://help.rallydev.com/rally-application-manager) authentication.

The constructor for v2.0.1:

```
restApi = new RallyRestApi("_abc123","https://rally1.rallydev.com","v2.0");
```

The constructor for v3.0.1:

```
restApi.Authenticate("_abc123", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", allowSSO: false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and noticed it was not recognizing my username and password that I had stored in the `<appSettings>` section of `Web.config`.
For some reason it would not allow them to be read so I decided to store the credentials elsewhere, in Properties => Settings of my app and it has worked ever since.

Here's a code snippet of how the Rally API initialization looks like for me:

```
RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(webServiceVersion: "v2.0");

string user = Properties.Settings.Default.username;
string pass = Properties.Settings.Default.password;
string rallyURL = Properties.Settings.Default.rallyURL;

restApi.Authenticate(user, pass, rallyURL, proxy: null, allowSSO: false);
```

Hope it helps!