# Getting error "RallyRESTAPIError: 422 Not authorized to perform action: Invalid key" when trying to create Rally test case

Tags: python, rest, rally, pyral

The code below works fine before until I try it today:

```
...
tc_data = {'Description': 'Test Case Dummy', 'c_QATCPARAMSTEXT': 'GET|/users/$id[1]|||200|{"id":"$id","firstname":"$firstname","lastname":"$lastname","email":"$email","role":"$role"}|||||||DeleteUser;logout|||||login;CreateUser||{"user[email]":"$admin_email","user[password]":"$admin_password"};{"user[email]":"$standard_email","user[firstname]":"$standard_firstname","user[lastname]":"$standard_lastname","user[role]":"$standard_role","user[password]":"$standard_password"}|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||', 'Objective': '', 'LastBuild': '', 'TestFolder': '', 'Type': 'Acceptance', 'Method': 'Automated', 'Expedite': 'false', 'Name': 'Test Case Dummy'}

tc = self.rally.put('TestCase', tc_data)
...
```

It shows error: "RallyRESTAPIError: 422 Not authorized to perform action: Invalid key" and the test case cannot be created. This is also happening when I try to create a build. However, the GET request works fine as usual.

This seems to happen to developers using java and C# Rally wrapper as well: [.Net Rally.RestApi error “Not authorized to perform action: Invalid key” when creating Rally test folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492008/net-rally-restapi-error-not-authorized-to-perform-action-invalid-key-when-cr). Please help!

Comment: I am also getting the same problem. I am using a java app made with  rally-rest-api (v2.0.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a defect and Rally is working to fix it. In the interim, the workaround that is confirmed to have worked for people who originally reported it is to use [ApiKey](https://help.rallydev.com/rally-application-manager) instead of basic (username/password) authentication. [Pyral 1.1.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyral) supports ApiKey. This assumes you are on rally1.rallydev.com, and not on sandbox.rallydev.com. ApiKey is not supported on sandbox.

Comment: Has there been any fix for it yet?

Comment: a fix was deployed Friday afternoon